# After login home page loaded twice in angular 6

Tags: html, css, angular, angular6

As I am new to angular, I am having a login page. I clicked on sign in button it's redirecting to the home page but its loading twice. In my angular web application, there are different starter component i.e header, footer, content, left sidebar. when my application loads and login hits by default that time I am hiding the left sidebar, header, footer, content. then after click on signin button its load home page twice. so I am not getting what is an issue. I am using AdminLTE Template.
Can any one suggest?

```
**login.component.html**

<body class="hold-transition login-page">
  <div class="login-box">
    <div class="login-logo">
      <a href="#"><b>OneMigrate</b></a>
    </div>
    <!-- /.login-logo -->
    <div class="login-box-body">
      <p class="login-box-msg">Sign in to start your session</p>

      <form>
        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
          <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope form-control-feedback"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
          <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <!-- <div class="col-xs-8">
            <div class="checkbox icheck">
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox"> Remember Me
              </label>
            </div>
          </div> -->
          <!-- /.col -->
          <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
          <div class="col-xs-4">
            <button (click)="signin()" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat">Sign In</button>
          </div>
          <!-- /.col -->
          <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
        </div>
      </form>  
    </div>
    <!-- /.login-box-body -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.login-box -->

  </body>


  **app-routing.module.ts**

import { AdminDashboard2Component } from './../admin/admin-dashboard2/admin-dashboard2.component';
import { AdminDashboard1Component } from './../admin/admin-dashboard1/admin-dashboard1.component';
import { StarterComponent } from './../starter/starter.component';
import { NewRunDetailsComponent } from '../newrundetails/new-run-details.component'
import { EnvironmentSettingComponent } from '../environmentsetting/environment-setting.component';
import { AdminComponent } from './../admin/admin.component';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from  '../home/home.component';
import { RunDetailsComponent } from '../rundetails/run-details.component'
import { UploadfileComponent}  from  '../uploadfile/uploadfile.component';
import { RunhistoryComponent} from '../runhistory/runhistory.component';
import { AppInsightsService } from '../services/app-insights.service';
import { DetailrunhistoryComponent} from '../detailrunhistory/detailrunhistory.component';
import { PendingRunsComponent } from '../pendingruns/pendingruns.component';
import { PendingRunsDetailComponent} from '../pendingrunsdetail/pendingrunsdetail.component';
import { LoginComponent } from '../login/login.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
      { path: 'newrundetails', component: NewRunDetailsComponent },
      { path: 'environmentsetting', component: EnvironmentSettingComponent},
      { path: 'rundetails', component: RunDetailsComponent},
      { path: 'pendingruns', component: PendingRunsComponent},
      { path: 'runhistory', component: RunhistoryComponent},
      { path: 'detailrunhistory', component:DetailrunhistoryComponent},
      { path: 'pendingrunsdetail',component:PendingRunsDetailComponent},
      { path: 'login',component:LoginComponent},

    ],{ useHash: true })
  ],
  declarations: [],
  exports: [ RouterModule]


})
export class AppRoutingModule { }

**login.component.ts**

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  // public wrapper: boolean = false;
  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  signin(){
  this.router.navigate(['home']);      
  }
}


**app.component.ts**

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router,NavigationStart } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']

})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  public title = 'app';
 public wrappercontent: boolean = false; 

  constructor(private router: Router) {

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // debugger;
    this.router.navigate(['login']);
    // this.wrappercontent=true;    

    this.router.events.forEach((event) => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
        if (event['url'] == '/login') {   
          this.wrappercontent=false;
        } else{      
          this.wrappercontent=true;     
        }
      }
     });
 }
}


 **app.component.html**

<router-outlet></router-outlet>  

<body hold-transition="" class="skin-blue sidebar-mini" style="height: auto;"> 
<div class="wrapper" *ngIf="wrappercontent"> 
       <app-starter-header ></app-starter-header>
       <app-starter-left-side></app-starter-left-side>
       <app-starter-content></app-starter-content> 
       <app-starter-footer></app-starter-footer>
       <app-starter-control-sidebar></app-starter-control-sidebar>
       <div class="control-sidebar-bg"></div>    
</div>
</body>

**home.component.html**
<div class="row img_full" *ngIf="this.show">
  <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <div>
      <div>
        <h3 class="box-title"></h3>
      </div>
      <div class="loader" *ngIf="showLoader"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i></div>
      <div class="box-body" *ngIf="!showLoader">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <button (click)="newRun()" class="pull-right button newRun">
              <img src="/assets/images/NewRun_white.png" class="newrun_btn" /> NEW RUN
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <button (click)="settings()" class="pull-right button settingEnv">
              <img src="/assets/images/E_Setting.png" class="newrun_btn" /> SETTINGS
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-2">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <br>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide some code, ideally on stackblitz to reproduce the issue

Comment: Please provide html an ts file.also,provide routing code from app.module or app.routes.

Comment: its more better if you create an example on stackblitz , as far as I can guess is your home component also child component of 'app-starter-content'?

Comment: yes @Bilal ..Home component is child component of app-starter-content if i remove that app-starter-content then nothing is loaded on page and i have called that in app.component.html when page initiate

Comment: any suggestion?

Comment: @Bilal I am sharing the link of stackblitz project structure. u can refer that link to understand project structure.link is [ link ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pjj3cu?embed=1&file=src/app/login/login.component.html)

Comment: @mchl18 can u plz suggest

Comment: @omkar can u please comment.I have added the files

Comment: where is your ts file ??